# Java: Why can't I declare the reference-variable in one statement and create the referenced object in another statement of the class?

Tags: java, class, object, syntax-error

```
// That doesn't work: 

import java.io.File;

public class Test {
    File file1;
    file1 = new File("path");
}

//--------------------------------------

// The following works:

import java.io.File;

public class Test {
    File file1 = new File("path");
}
```

I don't understand why the first version is not possible.
I also tried it with an int-value (which is not an object - I think):

```
//Also doesn't work:

public class Test {
    int number;
    number = 4;
}
```

---

Thank you! I tried it and it works (without implementing a non-default constructor or a method):

```
import java.io.File;

public class Test {
    int number;
    {
        number = 4;
    }
    File file1;
    {
        file1 = new File("path");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        System.out.print(test.number + " , " + test.file1.getName());
// Output: 4 , path
    }
}
```

Comment: you're having a statement somewhere "loose" in the class. If you want it that way, you should have your file1 = new File("path"); in your constructor, an initialization block or a method

Comment: Your first attempt is invalid Java. A variable declaration and setting its initial value must be one statement at class scope.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you cannot have executable code in the class definition outside a method. So the line

```
file1 = new File("path");
```

(which is a statement), is illegal. It never gets executed. The class definition is processed at compile time, but the compiler is not a virtual machine, it doesn't execute your code. Statements are executed at runtime.

You can, as B.M noted, create a static piece of code which is executed when the class is loaded. But, I believe it is equivalent to your second example:

```
File file1 = new File("path");
```

(but I admit not to have checked the bytecode for that).

Comment: I'm not sure this is strictly correct. It's not a case of the code not being executed at runtime. It's invalid Java and does not compile without an error.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a block statement :

```
public class Test {
    File file1 ;
     {
        file1 = new File("path");
     }
}
```

Comment: or with a constructor.